# firebase.storage() is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm new to web development and firebase and a error is appearing to me. I've not been able to solve it so came here to seek for help.

The error displayed is `firebase.storage() is not a function`. It seems that the firestorage is not set correctly in my computer. However, I've followed the instructions download from the google website itself and it did not change a thing.

I've seen some other questions regarding this on Stack Overflow, but they use node or react  which is not my case. Can someone give me a hint?

I know it is not explained in details because, as I said before, I'm not an expert. Please be compreensive and I'll develop better my question.

The code I've created is bellow. The first block is a subset of an *.html* file. The other one is the body of my *.js file*

```
  <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
      <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

      <!-- Inicializa o firebase -->
      <script>
          var config = {
              apiKey: "..",
              authDomain: "..",
              databaseURL: "..",
              projectId: "..",
              storageBucket: "..",
              messagingSenderId: "..",
              appId: ".."
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
      </script>
      <!-- Nosso app -->
      <script src="./app.js"></script>
```

---

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
var stringInput = document.getElementById('string-input');

var ref = firebase.storage();

fileInput.onchange = function (event) {
}

stringInput.onchange = function (event) {

}
```

Comment: Where's the `script` tag for Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to include the firebase storage api.

You can do this by adding this line after you import the `firebase-app` script:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

You can see a demo in this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vqy01k5175