# Why does firebase.app().storage() tell me that storage is not a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Google Cloud Storage. I'm following along in this guide here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

It gives an example of how to reference a storage bucket:

```
var storage = firebase.app().storage("gs://my-custom-bucket");
```

This is for a non-default storage bucket.

It also gives an example of how to reference s storage bucket for a custom app:

```
var storage = customApp.storage();
```

I'm not using a custom app nor am I using a non-default storage bucket. So I assume the syntax in my case is:

```
var storage = firebase.app().storage();
```

Yet this doesn't work. It tells me firebase.app().storage is not a function.

This is how I initialize firebase:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const config = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "...",
        measurementId: "..."
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Why would it say that `firebase.app().storage` is not a function?

Comment: Did you do a google search on that error message?  I bet it comes up a lot.

Comment: This typically means that you forgot to import `firebase-storage.js`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066163/firebase-storage-is-not-a-function-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the end, I went with firebase-admin, using fbAdmin.storage().bucket(). <-- That works with my nodejs backend server.